# confirm message for delete button

Tags: javascript

Below code is my function in JavaScript I want confirm message after clicking delete button.

JavaScript

```
function deleteValues()
{

    var regno = document.getElementById('regs_numb').value;
    var patId =document.getElementById('Pat_Id').value; 
    if(regno ==""||isNaN(regno))
    {
         var el = document.createElement("div");
         el.setAttribute("style","position:absolute;top:15%;left:80%;background-color:white;height:50px;width:150px;");
         el.innerHTML = "please enter register number";
         setTimeout(function(){
          el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
         },2000);
         document.body.appendChild(el);
        return false;
    }
    else if(patId =="")
    {
         var el1 = document.createElement("div");
         el1.setAttribute("style","position:absolute;top:15%;left:80%;background-color:white;height:50px;width:150px;");
         el1.innerHTML = "please enter patient id ";
         setTimeout(function(){
          el1.parentNode.removeChild(el1);
         },2000);
         document.body.appendChild(el1);
         return false;
    }
    else
    {       
        document.forms[0].action="deletePatient?regs_numb="+document.getElementById('regs_numb').value+"&&Pat_Id="+document.getElementById('Pat_Id').value;
        document.forms[0].submit();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle? jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

I would check out Javascript's build in `confirm` method.

```
var s = confirm("Are you sure you want to do this?");
if(s){
  // Proceed
}else{
  // Uh oh, go back!
}
```

See here for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple solution

```
function ConfirmDelete()
{
  var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
  if (x)
      return true;
  else
    return false;
}


<input type="button" Onclick="ConfirmDelete()">
```

Comment: Include this function instead of yours. It is easy to do.

Comment: my requirement is i had to give regs no and pat id after that i should click delete. based on those two values the row should be delete in database.......without confirm message it deleting successfully .but i want confirm message

Answer (score 0):

Try window.confirm() method.

Example

```
var r = confirm("Delete?");
if (r == true)
{
  //code to delete
}
else
{
  //cancel
}
```

Read more at
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
else
{
    document.forms[0].action="deletePatient?regs_numb="+document.getElementById('regs_numb').value+"&&Pat_Id="+document.getElementById('Pat_Id').value;
    document.forms[0].submit();
    return true;
}
```

have something like

```
else
{
    var isSure = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete ' + patId + '?');

    if (isSure) {
        document.forms[0].action="deletePatient?regs_numb="+document.getElementById('regs_numb').value+"&&Pat_Id="+document.getElementById('Pat_Id').value;
        document.forms[0].submit();
        return true;
    }
}
```

this will pop up a confirmation message with <kbd>Ok</kbd> and <kbd>Cancel</kbd> buttons. The form will submit only if the user clicks on <kbd>Ok</kbd>

**EDIT:** You might also have a mistake here

```
document.forms[0].action="deletePatient?regs_numb="+document.getElementById('regs_numb').value+"&&Pat_Id="+document.getElementById('Pat_Id').value;
                      // ------------------------------------------------------------------------^ You have 2 "&" symbols
```

Comment: @saideep are you getting any errors in console? `confirm` is a standard JavaScript function so it should work all the time

Comment: integer column  cannot be null and in my browser page it saying already existing user

Comment: my requirement is i had to give regs no and pat id after that i should click delete. based on those two values the row should be delete in database.......without  using confirm message it deleting successfully .but i want confirm message –

Comment: @saideep check to make sure that it is getting the `regs_numb` and `pat_id` values correctly (see my update). There must be an error somewhere

Comment: @saideep instead of the code I posted try this `var isSure = confirm("Delete?");`. This is a simpler message that doesn't include the `patId` variable